# Ember 2, Handle two or more properties in just one computed property. How to filter by search text and category

Tags: ember.js, filter, ember-data, computed-properties

My code is here:

https://ember-twiddle.com/b894cec64a1d78a71e15b642d512cfcf

I need to use this computed property: "postsFiltered" with both Category and Search but when I change category on clickCategory() I need to reset the search text (if present).

But then the computed property is already called? No?

And the same when I search something I need to reset category to null.

```
postsFiltered: Ember.computed('category', 'search', function () {

var posts = this.get('posts');
var search = this.get('search');

console.log('computed postsFiltered() with category: ' + this.get('category') + ', search: ' + search);
return posts.filter((item) => item['categoryId'] === this.get('category'));

// or this when I search, but I don't know how to do one or the other:
// return posts.filter((item) => item['name'].includes(search));
})
```

How to handle two properties in the same computed property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to introduce `search:'',` in controller, and pass it down to posts component `{{my-posts posts=posts category=category search=search}}` and your `clickCategory` should reset search property when category clicked

```
clickCategory(categoryId) {
   this.set('category', categoryId);
   this.set('search','');
}
```

This will ensure that you are following Data Down Actions Up strategy. [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/efc7d4256c64714cee8ea259699bdf2c?openFiles=components.my-posts.js%2C)

Edit:

1. [Ember.computed.filterBy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_filterBy) here the last argument is an value not the property name
2. [Ember.computed.filter](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_filter) We can't use it either since we need to include one more dependancy too`category`
3. So finally implemented our own computed property instead inbuilt macros,

```
    categoryPosts: Ember.computed('posts.[]','category', function(){ 
      return this.get('posts').filter(post => post.categoryId === this.get('category'));
    }),
```

Comment: Dear @kumkanillam, thanks for your answer.

Another person recommended me this: https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/handle-two-or-more-properties-in-just-one-computed-property/12624/2 **What do you think?**

Comment: Combining mine and discussion thread input,i think you can get what you want, look at this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/efc7d4256c64714cee8ea259699bdf2c?openFiles=components.my-posts.js%2C).

Comment: In your last twiddle (https://ember-twiddle.com/efc7d4256c64714cee8ea259699bdf2c) the category click doesn't show posts.

Comment: Look at this updated twiddle which fixes https://ember-twiddle.com/efc7d4256c64714cee8ea259699bdf2c?openFiles=components.my-posts.js%2C I updated the reason in answer

Comment: thanks a lot. can I ask you why `posts.[]` and `categoryPosts.[]`??

Comment: In your case it's not required, that will be useful when we add/remove entries from array it will trigger computed property calculation again. well explained here https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/